# Undefined variable: min_height

Tags: php, wordpress

I´m a noob with php and similars.
My problem is this:

> Notice: Undefined variable: min_height in /var/www/vhosts/colegiomarcotemondariz.es/httpdocs/wp-content/themes/Total_old/vc_templates/vc_row.php on line 197

ANd the code line is this:

```
// Min Height
if ( $min_height ) {
    // Sanitize
    $min_height = esc_html( $min_height );
    if ( ! preg_match('/[A-z]/', $min_height ) && strpos( $min_height, '%' ) === false ) {
        $min_height = $min_height .'px;';
    }
    // Add inline style
    if ( $min_height ) {
        $inline_style .= 'min-height:'. $min_height .';';
    }
}
```

any help?
THX!! and sorry for my english!!

Comment: Welp, where do you define `$min_height`?

Comment: Simply, use `if(isset($min_height))` instead of `if($min_height)`. Older versions of PHP allowed that type of syntax, but newer versions do not.

Comment: thx!!.. i try this now!

Comment: I was mid-answering this and you closed it 

Comment: nooo!!.. i dont close nothing!!

Comment: For that opening if-statement condition, can you try using `if (isset($min_height))` instead of `if ($min_height)`? In PHP, checking the value of a variable that does not exist can produce errors like this.

If you are trying to make sure the value is positive, then check isset first and then check that the value is positive using `intval()`. If you also need to make sure the value is a number, you can check the type using `gettype()`.

Comment: Also, you're better off using `!empty($min_height)` than `isset($min_height)` because it ensures the value itself is not `=== false`, so you can rest assured there’s a truthy value contained.

Comment: thx a lot!! both members help me!! my page is now running good!!